# pandas losing index after GroupBy while removing duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to retain all rows except duplicate rows with non-max amount.
So, eventually I'll have all rows with non-duplicates.

Input

```
df
   name  amount
0     a    1000
1     a    2000
2     a    5000
3     b    1000
4     b    2000
5     c    3000
6     d    4000
7     e    5000
8     f    6000
9     g    7000
10    h    8000
11    h   10000
```

Expected Output:

[image]

```
dd = df[df.duplicated(['name'], keep=False)]
idx = dd.groupby(['name'], sort=False)['amount'].max()
```

This gives me a series without index values w.r.t df.
How can I get the expected output?

Comment: Better solution is without groupby: `df.sort_values('amount', ascending=False).drop_duplicates('name')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can avoid the `groupby` and retain the index using `sort_values` and `drop_duplicates`:

```
df.sort_values('amount', ascending=False).drop_duplicates('name').sort_index()


   name  amount
2     a    5000
4     b    2000
5     c    3000
6     d    4000
7     e    5000
8     f    6000
9     g    7000
11    h   10000
```

You can avoid the last `sort_index` call with:

```
df[~df.sort_values('amount', ascending=False).name.duplicated()]

   name  amount
2     a    5000
4     b    2000
5     c    3000
6     d    4000
7     e    5000
8     f    6000
9     g    7000
11    h   10000
```

With the understanding that boolean indexing reindexes the DataFrame. You will have to be okay with the `UserWarning`, however:

> ```
> UserWarning: Boolean Series key will be reindexed to match DataFrame index.
> ```

---

**Special Case**
Since your data appears to be sorted already, you can just do

```
df[~df.duplicated('name', keep='last')]

   name  amount
2     a    5000
4     b    2000
5     c    3000
6     d    4000
7     e    5000
8     f    6000
9     g    7000
11    h   10000
```

This won't work in general, however.

Answer (score 1):

May check `idxmax`

```
df.loc[df.groupby('name').amount.idxmax()]
   name  amount
2     a    5000
4     b    2000
5     c    3000
6     d    4000
7     e    5000
8     f    6000
9     g    7000
11    h   10000
```